# $g(x)=\sup \{f(y): y\in B(x)\}$ is lsc on $R^{n}$ where $B(x)$ is a open ball with fixed radius $r$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This is exercise 4.11 in Zygmund's book "Measure and Integral" edition 1, the statement is as follows:

Let $f$ be defined on $R^{n}$ and let $B(x)$ denote the open ball $\{y:|y-x|<r\}$ with center $x$ and fixed radius $r$. Show that the function $g(x)=sup\{f(y): y\in B(x)\}$ is lsc (lower semicontinuous).

My approach is as follows: I tried to show that $K_{a} = \{x\in R^{n}: g(x)\leq a\}$ is closed for all finite $a$. Let $x_{0}$ be a limit point of $K_{a}$ and $\{x_{n}\}$ be a sequence in $K_{a}$ that converges to $x_{0}$. I want to show that $g(x_{0}) = sup\{f(y): y\in B(x_{0})\}\leq a$, and I can imagine the open balls $B(x_{n})$ slowly coinciding with $B(x_{0})$ when $x_{n}$ and $x_{0}$ gets very close.

If they coincide then I'm done. But for all $y\in B(x_{0})$, $|y-x_{n}|\leq |y-x_{0}|+|x_{0}-x_{n}| < r+\frac{1}{n}$, so it seems that I cannot claim that $B(x_{0})=B(x_{n})$ for $n$ being large enough.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint : I use what you have done. Fix $y\in B(x_0)$ Then $|y-x_0|=u<r$. Now choose $n$ such that  $|x_0-x_n|<r-u$. Then $|y-x_n|<r$, ie $y\in B(x_n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $d(y,x_0) <r$ then $d(y,x_n) <r$ for $n$ sufficiently large. [To be explicit $d(y,x_n) \leq d(y,x_0)+d(x_0,x_n) <r$ whenever $d(x_n,x_0) <r-d(y,x_0)$]. Fix one such $n$. Then $y \in B(x_n)$ so $f(y) \leq a$. This is true for all $y \in B(x_0)$ . Taking supremum over $y$ we get $g(x_0) \leq a$.